# In AJAX Function .remove() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In a jQuery click function using `$.post()` I have a `.remove()` function nested within the response function if the response returns true.  My `alert()` appears to work correctly with the code is processed, however the `.remove()` does not seem to work whatsoever even though the `alert()` code in the same space appears to process.  The same code when placed outside of `$.post()` works just fine.

```
var container = $(".container");
var delete = $("a.delete");
var dataId = $(delete).data("dataid");

delete.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("url.php",
        {'data': dataId},
        function(response) {
            if (response == true) {
                alert("IT WORKED");
                $(this).closest(container).remove();
            }
        },
        "json"
    );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the following change and it should work. In the success callback `this` is the `jqXHR` object, therefore you have to cache `this` before the ajax call:

```
delete.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);
    $.post("url.php",
        {'data': dataId},
        function(response) {
            if (response == true) {
                alert("IT WORKED");
                that.closest(container).remove();
            }
        },
        "json"
    );
});
```

Comment: FYI, `this` inside success callback is the jqXHR, not `window` ;)

Comment: can also pass `context` option to `$.ajax`

Comment: Magnifiecient! Thanks! Would one have to use `$.ajaxSetup()` when using a shorthand form like in this case?

Comment: @PeterKA ajaxSetup is global, so you'd have to reset it on specific `this` before each ajax requests, not a great idea. Easier way is to use a referenced variable as in this answer if you want to use ajax shorthand methods

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other answer, one could also use the [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) function to associate the context with what you might desire.

For example:

```
delete.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("url.php",
        {'data': dataId},
        $.proxy(function(response) {
            if (response == true) {
                alert("IT WORKED");
                $(this).closest(container).remove();
            }
        }, this),
        "json"
    );
});
```